# How to have a separate image style for an image field for the 1st views row?

Tags: views, 8, theming

First I tried with views_conditional (which was already installed on the site) to check for 1st row and output the specific image but it does not seem to work [as per this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional/issues/2867595)

Ideally I want to do it without installing an extra module.

I tried with `THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view_field` but the image was already rendered at this stage.  Have used the somewhat hackish str_replace but it does not actually work.

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view_field(&$vars) {
  if($vars['view']->element['#name'] == "free_write" 
      && $vars['field']->field == "field_main_image" 
      && $vars['row']->index == 1 
      ){
    $html = str_replace("teaser_media_small","teaser_media_medium",$vars["output"]->__toString());
    $vars["output"] = Drupal\Core\Render\Markup::create($html);
  }
}
```

what is the proper way to do this in a preprocess function or perhaps in a twig template ?

Comment: I think the solution from @Adrian Cid Almaguer is the best for your field based view. You might consider for better performance and theming a view displaying content and then switch view modes in a row style plugin, see this module https://www.drupal.org/project/views_parity_row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution can be Add an Attachment Display to the View, in the Attachment you can select to show only one element with a different style and you can give as position Before.

[image]

In the Page then you select to skip 1 element.

[image]

This will output something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another option, is to simply <kbd>add</kbd> your image field again and give it the other image style and only print this field in the first row via preprocess function.

If you want to use twig, you can add "count" as a field and use that to know which row you're on in your conditional.